# Bot framework missing project.json on deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linux, botframework

I've developed a bot with Microsoft Botframework using .NET assuming it would run perfectly fine under my linux web host. However, when I publish it to file, transfer it to my linux environment and try to run it with `dotnet run` I get the following error message:

`error DOTNET1017: Project file does not exist '/my/path/bot/project.json'`

The project never created a `project.json` and while I can create one I am beginning to wonder if it is even possible at all to run bot framework under linux at this time. But it seems like everything is on .NET Core so I can't see why not.

I can create the project.json, but I don't know what it should contain. Any ideas?

Comment: Bot Framework isn't on .NET Core yet: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/572 https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1767

Comment: @AnnaZietlow if you make that as an answer, I can accept it!

Comment: Cheers, @staticelf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfotunately, Bot Framework isn't on .NET Core yet:

https://www.github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/572 https://www.github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1767